# What is the correct way to pass an array argument pointer to a foreign function using ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

My question is related to the following type of error message

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_long instance instead of LP_c_long_Array_9
```

It occurred from running the following code

```
from ctypes import *

DLL = windll.test

ex = DLL.ex_
ex.rstype = None
ex.argtypes = ( POINTER(c_int), )

N = 9
N_array = (c_int * N)() 

for i in xrange(N):
    N_array[i] = i + 3 

N_array_p = pointer( N_array )
DLL.ex_( N_array_p  )
```

The external function `ex` takes a single pointer to int argument. It modifies the contents of the `N_array`, so I thought that I needed to create the pointer `N_array_p` but that appears to be wrong.

I appear to be able to fix the problem simply by passing the array to the function without creating a pointer `DLL.ex_( N_array  )`. However, is that the correct way to do things? Can I rely on this working?

I note in the ctypes documentation (15.17.1.15)

> In addition, if a function argument is explicitly declared to be a pointer type (such as POINTER(c_int)) in argtypes, an object of the pointed type (c_int in this case) can be passed to the function. ctypes will apply the required byref() conversion in this case automatically.

But, `byref` is used (as I understand it) when one does not want to modify the referenced object. Here, I do want to modify the array and indeed it seems that I can. So what is going on? Ctypes seems to have generated a pointer for me, rather than a reference.

BTW, I can also get the code to work using `cast` to change the pointer type

```
N_array_p = cast( N_array, POINTER(c_int) )
```

but if I can pass arrays directly that would be better (because I have rather large argument lists).

Comment: Thanks @eryksun, so I don't need to bother with a cast in this case :-) I wrote "appears to be wrong" because the error occurs. I don't think I am hiding any Python code from you, so it seems indeed to be incorrect. Why do you say "it works"?

Comment: Sorry, it helps to check. I overlooked how finicky ctypes can be about type checks. `pointer( N_array )` creates an `LP_c_int_Array_9`, which unfortunately isn't accepted for an `LP_c_int` parameter. Anyway, just pass the array directly, without creating a pointer or using `byref`, since C arrays are automatically passed as a pointer to the first element.